# How to stop escaping field name in smarty?

Tags: php, html, smarty

My code is -

```
{html_checkboxes name=ms_fields['company_type'] options=$comp_type separator='<br />'}
```

Which is generating -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ms_fields[\'company_type\'][]" value="0">
```

How can i get the name be - `name="ms_fields['company_type'][]"`?

If it is ok then no problem. New to `smarty`, so little confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value for argument `name` into quotes:

```
{html_checkboxes name="ms_fields['company_type']" options=$comp_type separator='<br />'}
```

Even better, also remove the apostrophes; you don't need them and they make difficult getting the values from `$_POST[]` on the script that processes the form:

```
{html_checkboxes name="ms_fields[company_type]" options=$comp_type separator='<br />'}
```

Comment: WHat about setting the `id` with the values of that array?